# How do I create a blank Google Spreadsheet using Drive API?

Tags: javascript, google-sheets, google-drive-api, google-sheets-api

I created a web interface and I am trying to create a blank Google Spreadsheet with Drive API.

How do I create a blank Google Spreadsheet?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use [Drive API](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/insert) by setting the [MIME Type](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIME) to `application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet`

```
from apiclient import errors
from apiclient.http import MediaFileUpload
# ...

def insert_file(service, title, description, parent_id, mime_type, filename):
  """Insert new file.

  Args:
    service: Drive API service instance.
    title: Title of the file to insert, including the extension.
    description: Description of the file to insert.
    parent_id: Parent folder's ID.
    mime_type: MIME type of the file to insert.
    filename: Filename of the file to insert.
  Returns:
    Inserted file metadata if successful, None otherwise.
  """
  media_body = MediaFileUpload(filename, mimetype=mime_type, resumable=True)
  body = {
    'title': title,
    'description': description,
    'mimeType': mime_type
  }
  # Set the parent folder.
  if parent_id:
    body['parents'] = [{'id': parent_id}]

  try:
    file = service.files().insert(
        body=body,
        media_body=media_body).execute()

    # Uncomment the following line to print the File ID
    # print 'File ID: %s' % file['id']

    return file
  except errors.HttpError, error:
    print 'An error occured: %s' % error
    return None
```

Note: Apps creating shortcuts with files.insert must specify the MIME type application/vnd.google-apps.drive-sdk.